# leaflet.browser.print doesn't work with React + TypeScript

Tags: leaflet

A question about Leaflet plugin for printing the map:
https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.browser.print

I am curious if it is supposed to work in React + TypeScript?
After the package is installed. I am trying to do an import

```
import "leaflet.browser.print/dist/leaflet.browser.print"
```

and I have a compile error: *Module Not Found*. but it is really in node_modules by this address.
Is there anything specific that has to be done to use this library with React + TS?

If I just install the package without any import and write

```
var browserControl = L.control.browserPrint({position: 'topLeft'}).addTo(instance)
```

it also won't work
*TypeError: leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.control.browserPrint is not a function* if I suppress with @ts-ignore. Otherwise TS will tell me "Property 'browserPrint' doesn't exist on type 'typeof Control'

How to import this plugin with React + TS?